# How to bind an Ethereum H160 address with a Substrate H256 address?

Tags: frontier, account

I'm trying to bind a H160 address with a H256 address, if we
assume this function:

```rust
fn bind(origin: OriginFor<T>, address: H160 , signature: [u8; 130]) -> Result<(), Error<T>>{
    // check the signature belonging to an address
    ensure!(check_signature(address, signature), Error<T>);

    // bind the sender with the address
    create_account(sender, address);

    Ok(())
}
```

Is this function available in Substrate? Or do you have any advice on how to do the bind function?

Comment: The "bind" function you want to create seems very similar to what the [Proxy account](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-proxies) system does. Have to looked at [that code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/proxy/src/lib.rs) to see how it works?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, it would help to get context on what you're trying to achieve. The H160 format is just the first 20 bytes of the H256 address. The function you're proposing should probably be taking some H256 address and then making the conversion to H160 by truncating it.

Comment: In acala they provide a mapping pallete https://wiki.acala.network/build/development-guide/smart-contracts/get-started-evm/evm-account

Answer (score 10):

H160 has a few *flavors* that you might pursue in the context of a Substrate chain:

- If you are looking to *map* H160 Ethereum addresses to, say, [SR25519](https://docs.moonbeam.network/learn/features/unified-accounts/) that is most common in Substrate chains, it is good to see the implementation in [Frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/) as a reference. Here a *truncated* hash scheme is used (H256 -> H160 by taking the first 160 (LE) bytes in the address). There are some tools to inspect truncated vs. Ethereum converted (ECDSA <-> SR25519) addresses [in the frontier node template](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/c20e13ccea1bc04d82ed5a609c6ccf7d3ec413f4/template/utils/README.md#substrate-evm-utilities).
- Another important example is to use H160 addresses as the *base* for accounting in you chain, this is exemplified in [Moonbeam's Unified Accounts](https://docs.moonbeam.network/learn/features/unified-accounts/)

Answer (score 1):

because [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/pull/1019#event-8782511081) was merged, Frontier now also supports Moonbeam's Unified Accounts (aka `AccountId20`)